# Separating keywords by space and searching MySQL database

Tags: mysql, keyword, sql-like

I am working with PHP and MySQL. I'll provide a simple table below:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  id |                    text                      |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog | 
------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like users to be able to search using keywords separated by spaces. I've got a simple SQL query for the above which is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE %[$keyword]%` which means if  I search for "The quick fox", I won't get any results. Is there a way to separate the keywords by spaces so if I search for "The quick fox", it will run 3 searches. One for "The", one for "quick", and one for "fox" - removing all white spaces. Though it should only display one result since it all belongs to the same row instead of 3 since all 3 keywords matched the data in the row.

What's the best way to do this? All suggestions to do this better are always welcome. Thanks!

[EDIT]

Just thought of this now, would separating the keywords by comma (,) be a better option?

Comment: You should almost certainly be handling this in the code that generates the query, rather than inside MySQL. (Also, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.)

Comment: Thanks for the concern, @ruakh. I do have that covered though. I just didn't want to put everything as I wanted people to focus on what I was asking for. But thanks, again.

Comment: O.K., but I stand by my statement that you should almost certainly be handling this in the code that generates the query, rather than inside MySQL. So to get the best answers, you should show the code that generates the query.

Comment: Yes, @ruakh. That would be one of the BEST ways to do it - as I was asking. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider a [regular expression via `REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.htm) to separate the words into an or group.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE
  LOWER(`text`) REGEXP '\b(the|quick|fox)\b'
```

Matches:

- *The quick* brown *fox* jumps over the lazy dog
- *Quick*, get *the fox*!
- I ate *the* cake

Doesn't match

- Brown dogs

Inside PHP, you can construct this expression by splitting your search string on the spaces and imploding it back on `|` after escaping each component.

```
$str = "the quick brown fox";
$kwds = explode(" ", $str);
$kwds = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $kwds);
$regexp = "\b(" . implode("|", $kwds) . ")\b";
```

Then use `REGEXP '$regexp'` in your statement.

#### Addendum:

Since you didn't mention it in the OP, I want to be sure you aware of MySQL's full text searching capabilities on MyISAM tables, in case it can meet your need. From your description, full text doesn't sound like exactly your requirement, but you should review it as a possibility: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: There you go. Thanks for focusing on the question, my friend. Let me try some of the things you've included here.

Comment: Should I use [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] instead of \b?

Comment: This doesn't seem to get any result from "Qui", it has to be "Quick" - any workaround?

Comment: @MikeSanchez This pattern will only get whole words. If you need partial matches from multiple keywords, you're going to need to construct a query with multiple `LIKE` clauses and some algorithm for cutting them down.

Answer (score 3):

I did it by a different approach of concatenating the query string.

//this line contains four words which are being used for a search
**$str = "the quick brown fox";**

//the query string is written in little pieces, stored in variable "$uquery"
**$uquery = "select * from tablename where";**

//a new variable "$keywords" is going to hold the values as an array
**$keywords = explode(" ", $str);**
**$keywords = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $keywords);**

//"$k" will be storing the total no. of elements in the array, should be holding "4" for this example
**$k = count($keywords);**

//defining variable "$i" equals to zero
**$i = 0;**

//initiating a while loop which will be continued 4 times as we have only 4 keywords in this example
**while($i <= $k){**

//here comes another new variable "$uquery_", following part will be concatenated with the previous piece of "$uquery" later
**$uquery_ .= " topic like convert(_utf8 '%$keywords[$i]%' USING latin1)";**

//for more explanation let me tell you that how "$keywords[$i]" will help in above piece of code, for every value of "$i" it will be fetching a keyword from the array, see below:
//$keywords[0]= "the" for $i =0
//$keywords[1]= "quick" for $i =1
//$keywords[2]= "brown" for $i =2
//$keywords[3]= "fox" for $i =3

//now concatenating logical && operator after every round of the loop in "$uquery_" but not for the last round as the query needs to be ended after last keyword
**if($i != $k){ $uquery_ .= " &&"; }**

//adding 1 to $i after every round
**$i++;**
}

//now our main variable "$uquery" is being concatenated with "$uquery_"
**$uquery .= "$uquery_";**

The above piece of code will be generating following query:
**select * from tablename where topic like convert(_utf8 '%the%' USING latin1) && topic like convert(_utf8 '%quick%' USING latin1) && topic like convert(_utf8 '%brown%' USING latin1) && topic like convert(_utf8 '%fox%' USING latin1)**

**Note:** "topic" is supposed to be the column name in mysql table, you can replace it with the column name as defined in your table.

I hope it will help a few of the people. If you have any questions feel free to ask me via Live Chat feature on my website http://www.79xperts.com

Regards

Adnan Saeed